# How do you set a custom theme for a .NET application?

Tags: c#, .net, themes, visual-styles

Much as the title says, I am wondering how to style a program like Photoshop CS4 or Autodesk Maya 2011. These programs are styled to where the UI looks completely custom. Right now I am using C# to program, but I can easily switch to C++ and WinAPI if it is easier. I have done multiple google searches for styling controls in C#, but there are seemingly no accurate results.

Much thanks for any help,
-Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a no easy task. [DevXpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Skins/) offer a wide range of skins with their components, so does [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/visual-style-builder.aspx).

There is a free library (without source) at [Skybound](http://dev.skybound.ca/Products/FreeStyle/), however this one is pretty old and not being developed anymore.

Answer (score 3):

If you using C#, WPF is a way to go, to make some custom UI. WinForms are not so modifiable.

Comment: Isn't WPF for .NET 4.0+ only? I'm on XP 32bit here, for I do not have much money ;) I'd really rather keep as much compatibility as I can. I have no problem with using unsafe code to style this thing.